# Modal Popup do not close if i click anywhere on screen

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

```html
 <div class="modal fade in" id="acc-del-form" role="dialog" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);" [ngStyle]="{'display':display}" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background: #05668D; color:#fff">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onCloseDeleteTagging()">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Update!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h5>Do you want to update tags</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-info btn-fill btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="updateTaggingData()">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-warning btn-fill btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onCloseDeleteTagging()">No</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my above modal popup it closes when i click on **onCloseDeleteTagging()** method

```js
onCloseDeleteTagging() {
    this.display = 'none';
  }
```

i want to close the modal pop to close when i click anywhere on the screen rather than clicking "X" button

```html
  <div class="pull-right" style="padding-top:15px;" [ngStyle]="{'display':TaggingUserDisplay}">

    <button type="button" title= "Save Tags" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill btn-xs" id="save_btn" (click)= "updateTaggingDataPopup()" [ngStyle]="{'display': 'updateTagBoList.length !== 0 '}"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>
```

this is my code to open modal popup

```js
  updateTaggingDataPopup() {
    this.display = "block";
  }
```

can any one help me in closing the popup when i click anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@HostListener` ([HostListener Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener))

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
clickOnDocument(event) {
  if(SOME_TEST_DO_YOU_WANT_TO_MAKE_PROBABLY_WITH_THE_event_TARGET){
     this.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: by doing this i am not able to open the modal popup.
  `@HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn) {
    if(this.settingsDisplay === 'block'){
      this.settingsDisplay = 'none';
    }
    
 }`

Comment: i guess i need to validate some other condition can you please guide me in from the above code. @distante

Comment: Why are you using `$event.target` ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, it's made with vanilla JS.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    target = evt.target;
    var modalContainer = document.getElementById('acc-del-form');
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal_block');
    if (target !== modal) {
        modalContainer.style.display = "none"
    }
})
```

When clicking anywhere outside the modal block it will remove the `display` attribute.

Comment: That is not a good way to do it in Angular because you could build yourself a memory leak.